# Separate timeouts for connection and response on HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, http, .net-core, .net-6.0

There are multiple ways for `HttpClient` calls to timeout/be cancelled: by setting the `HttpClient.Timeout` property, by passing in a `CancellationToken`, using a custom `HttpMessageHandler`, etc. The problem with all these approaches is that the timeout is met and the call is cancelled regardless of if the server couldn't be reached at all or if it just takes longer to respond.

An existing example of the behavior I want to implement is Postman:
When (for this example) my ASP.NET Core Web API is not currently running and I send a request via Postman it stops right after just 5 seconds or so. But when my Web API runs, I send a request via Postman and then hit a breakpoint in my code or add a delay or something, than Postman will wait the amount of milliseconds that was specified in its settings (= more than 5 seconds).

And that's kind of what I want to get to work. To have two different timeouts for my HTTP requests. One for waiting for a connection to the server and one for waiting for its response. Perfect would be if the call would also be cancelled when the connection to the server is interrupted while waiting for the response. Is something like this possible in C# (using .NET 6) and if yes, how?

Comment: Insomnia, for example, has this behavior, too.

Comment: That's the whole point of a timeout. If it's exceeded, the attempt fails. *Request* timeouts are used to prevent the client from waiting forever so yes, they're meant to cancel even after a connection succeeds. Otherwise a badly written server could crash the client. In fact, that's an actual hacking DoS technique. `Perfect would be if the call would also be cancelled` HTTP has no cancellation, it's a stateless protocol. You can only stop waiting for a response. You can't tell a server to abort a request with HTTP alone.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's a good question - he just wants to extent the timeout a little rather than endlessly wait. He clearly mentions two different timeouts

Comment: It's a good question about the wrong thing. You can increase the request timeout if you want. The vast majority of timeouts are *after* establishing a connection with the server - otherwise you get a DNS or connection timeout error.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the timer doesn't start from when a connection is established though (for `HttpClient`), does it?

Comment: It may start *after* the actual socket connection is established. Windows itself caches socket connections, which is why disposing an HttpClient is such a bad idea - the sockets remain open but can't be used. The second time you make an HTTP request to the same server, the already open TCP connection will be used. Again, HTTP itself has no notion of connections.

Comment: If you want to control cancellation, (not timeout), you can do so with a CancellationTokenSource. The CancellationToken is signalled when CancellationTokenSource.Cancel is called, not when a timeout expires. Timeouts are so common though, there's a constructor that will create a CTS that calls `Cancel` after a specific delay. In other cases calls to `Cancel` are made explicitly. You can call `Cancel` in your own code that combines multiple conditions eg checking a timer *and* a flag. You could use `Task.Delay()` and then check a flag to see if you really need to cancel or not

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edited the title to better reflect what I want to do. It's not about having no timeout at all, but to have separate timeouts, one for establishing a connection and one for waiting for the actual response. And I know that HTTP has no cancellation. By "call" I meant for example the `SendAsync` that should cancelled, as soon as the server connection drops while waiting for the actual response. The server will still continue processing, that I'm aware of.

Comment: @YungDeiza exactly that, two different timeouts. And correct the timeout starts before a connection is even established, so when I set a timeout of 10 seconds, the call will be cancelled after 10 seconds, even when for example the connection took 4 seconds and the response would've taken 10 seconds.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm aware of the CancellationTokenSource, I even mentioned it in my question. But it seems that it can't be utilized for what I want to do: Wait up 10 seconds for a connection and then, **if** a connection is possible up to 2 minutes to get the actual response (the numbers are of course only examples and their reasonableness is not part of this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can achieve what you want by passing an instance `SocketsHttpHandler` of to the constructor  of `HttpClient`.

`SocketsHttpHandler` has a `ConnectTimeout` property which will cause a timeout in `HttpClient` if a connection is not established before the specified duration elapses.

See the official Microsoft documentation on setting [Timeouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-8.0#:%7E:text=You%20can%20set%20some%20additional%20timeouts%20if%20you%20pass%20in%20a%20SocketsHttpHandler%20instance%20when%20constructing%20the%20HttpClient%20object%3A) in HttpClient for more details.

Answer (score 8):

When instantiating `HttpClient`, you're able to provide an implementation of `System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler`, I believe the default implementation is [`SocketsHttpHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler?view=net-8.0).

On the `SocketsHttpHandler` you're able to provide a connection timeout.

```
var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler
{
    ConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
};

var client = new HttpClient(handler);

// stuff as usual...
```

I prefer this to using a sanity check as there's no guarantee that if the first call succeeds that the second one will.

Comment: Given that the OS caches sockets, this may not have the effect the OP expects, as the socket may already be open when a request is made. 5 seconds may be too low as DNS resolution can take up to 15 seconds - that's the reason sockets are cached.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed here. Funny thing is, when the task is cancelled due to meeting the ConnectTimeout it still states "The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing." x'D

Comment: DNS caching is orthogonal to socket pooling, and I'm not sure of the specifics of what phases of the establishing the connection `ConnectTimeout` actually refers to (does it include DNS resolution, for example?).  I think this answer satisfies what OP is asking for, which is to ensure the connection is made before starting the request timeout.  I agree with your concerns however, there's a lot of moving pieces when making an HTTP request.

Comment: @ChristophMett yea it's kind of silly, I typically create an `HttpClient` with an infinite timeout, and then pass in my own cancellation token (with a `CancelAfter` defined on it) when calling `Send` so I can properly differentiate between connection timeouts, and request timeouts, and plain-ol' cancelled requests.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in my tests it (at least seems to) work. Only thing I found now is the following: When I send a request to my ASP.NET Core Web API and make it hit a breakpoint (so a connection was possible and it waits for the response), then kill the program performing the request, restart it and do the same call again without continuing in my Web API, the ConnectionTimeout is than hit. Can this be circumvented somehow? Because the server **is** reachable but it's not able to process a request right now.

Comment: @ChristophMett Timeouts and debugging is a pain, I've used `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached` to conditionally disable timeouts when I'm debugging my app, might be useful for you (depending on which app is being debugged, obviously).  Could also make the timeout configurable by an command-line or env-var.

Comment: @Matthew, that's not exactly what I meant. I'm debugging the Web API so I can't tell the client to use a longer timeout (or none at all), or I can, but it would be weird. What I observed is that when my Web API is currently waiting at a breakpoint and I send a request to it with the SocketsHttpHandler it will cancel after ConnectTimeout time. But if do a request via Postman while the breakpoint is being hold, Postman seems to know that the server is reachable but just unable to answer in this moment, so it waits the longer time. Could this be done with the SocketsHttpHandler, too?

Comment: Okay, that seems to be achievable by using the ConnectCallback property of the SocketsHttpHandler and passing a CancellationToken with the desired time to the `socket.ConnectAsync` call.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't understand you wrong, I resolve this issue in a critital service that I manage with a `sanity check`.

The `sanity check` is compose by an sample status method in the API that returns `200`. So for every `critital call` that I need a quick answer, I made a parallel sanity check. So two calls to the service: one for check the service/server and another one for the action itself. In this way I can handle what kind of timeout I'm working of, if server is gone or if action is delayed.

Comment: That would totally be an option. I thought of it, too. But always making two calls instead of one is not that pretty, so I was hoping for something better.

Comment: @ChristophMett yes, I didn't plan to make a tech answer but functional, its too long for a comment. We just use this for the business need (is a payment method) in order to external clients of the api can verify a three-way step of security with multiple tokens